# Finding the standard matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T: {\bf R}^2 \rightarrow {\bf R}^2$ is given by $T(x,y)=(x,2y)$.

```
Find the standard matrix of T
Is the standard matrix an invertible matrix?
Is T an isomorphism?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that matrix of $T$ is needed wrt the standard ordered basis $\mathbb B=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$ we have that

$T((1,0))=(1,0)=1(1,0)+0(0,1)$ and

$T((0,1))=(0,2)=0(1,0)+2(0,1)$

So we conclude

$[T]_{\mathbb B}=$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$

(Note that the coefficients are written column wise)

Immediately we can say that $[T]_{\mathbb B}$ is invertible since its determinant is $2\neq0$

To conclude  $T$ is isomorphism we see $T$ is one-one

since $(x_1,2y_1)=(x_2,2y_2)\Rightarrow x_1=x_2,y_1=y_2$ and

$T$ is onto since $\forall (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$ we have $T((x,\frac y2))=(x,y)$

Comment: thank you so much for your help:D

Comment: You are most welcome.